# How can I prevent unwanted double key actions?

Tags: keyboard, trackpoint, mousepad

I am using Xubuntu 18.04.4 LTS on a Lenovo ThinkPad W530.

If I hit hit not exactly (maybe also by accidentally pressing the mousepad or touching the trackpoint), the cursor lands in a completely different position. It is also possible that a part of the previously existing text gets marked by the unwanted double key action. Then the next writing key will overwrite it.

1. Is it possible to bind multi-key operations that lead to marking of text passages to the fact that **the key to be pressed in advance must have been pressed for at least a preset time** (e.g. 100 ms) before the next key press really counts as "extending marking"?
2. Is there any way to make sure that quickly consecutive keystrokes do not apply, but are **rejected with an acoustic signal if there is no minimum time span** (e.g. 100-200 ms) **between them?** For example, if I don't hit the desired number 1 exactly, but hit 2 together with it, I get 21, which is quite reproducible. The same applies to other adjacent keys. Which of two simultaneously pressed adjacent key is recognized first seems to depend on the key pair. In my experiments there were estimated only a few ms between closing the corresponding contacts. One should be able to reject such key strokes!
3. It is possible that unintentional mouse pad or trackpoint touch may cause the cursor to jump with or without selection of existing text. Therefore, it would also be helpful for people with disabilities **to reject multiple operations between keyboard, trackpoint and mousepad, which occur within adjustable short time periods**, also with an acoustic signal.

Is there a place where one can prevent such too fast unaccidential input device operations, e.g. "debounce" them?

Would it be possible to **automatically disable the mousepad and/or the trackpoint**, e.g. for the next second, once any key is hit an re-enable them automatically after such a given delay time has passed after the last keystroke of a series of keystrokes?

Answer (score 0):

A partial solution to my problem is to install the program **touchpad-indicator**. This can be done like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator
```

The installed program can be started from a command line using this command:

```
/usr/bin/touchpad-indicator
```

After it has been started, a small symbol shows up among the indicators (notification area for Bluetooth, WLAN, SplitScreen and the like).

Clicking on that one can choose whether the touchpad shall be deactivated while a real mouse is connected to the computer (I moved this switch to the left position which is ON), one ca further select for when `touchpad-indicator` starts or ends, whether the touchpad shall be left as it is enabled, disabled. I switched them both on “enabled”.

Then there is an option which I enabled in order to have the touchpad disabled for a given time (preset to 800 ms) after each keystroke. This is the setting for my computer if no mouse is attached to it and it works well.

On the second tab one can determine whether touchpad-indicator is started automatically with additional options whether to show a message that this has happened.

When I tried touchpad-indicator first I found out that it resolves 80% of my typing related issues, so I made an autostart entry for it by hand. Later after some searching I only found a Spanish instruction of use for the program at https://www.atareao.es/aplicacion/touchpad-indicator-para-ubuntu/ and only then I looked at the second tab which would have saved me some manual work. There is an excellent translation tool at https://www.deepl.com/en/translator and only later I read about the possibility to set touchpad-indicator for an automatic autostart without having to go through system functions, editing files and the like.

What is left: Occasionally I do not touch the key I mean exactly in the middle, but also slide the adjacent key. Its signal comes a few ms later and actually I want to suppress such keystrokes which appear within a predetermined time after their predecessor.

`xfce4-accessibility-settings` would be the right place for that, but the minimum times which can be set there are far too big for my purpose. They are meant for really handicapped people and for those one needs **Slow keys** and **Bounce keys** intervals in the settable range. If the lower bounds for them would be lowered to say 10 ms, my preferred setting of say 20 ms would be in that range and my other keyboard-related problem would also be solved.